# CGImageRef in OS X application?

Tags: c, macos, core-graphics

I have a .c code snipped that I don't want to port to Objective-C. This .c file worked on the iPhone platform, but not on OS X. It seems that the compiler doesn't know what to do with

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
```

and so it doesn't know *CGImageRef*:

```
ImageArray3D *ia3d_createWithCGImage(CGImageRef image, int nLargestElements);

   error: syntax error before 'image'
```

Your help is appreciated! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add ApplicationServices.framework to your target?